# Error in php / mysql upgrade script

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, upgrade

I'm trying to create an upgrade script, but somewhere seems to be an error causing the while loop never ending.

What I'm trying to do is to set a database field with the result of the upgrade code. Therefor I have 2 while loops. The first loop is to run trough all the user_id's, the second while loop is to calculate the percentage of all profile fields which each user has filled in.

I guess it's a logical error, because if I run the upgrade code without the first while loop by giving the exact user_id, it's working fine.
Or could it be the problem, that some user_id's dont exist anymore?

Please have a look at the code:

```
$count_userid = 1;

       while($count_userid < 10000)
        {  

    // profile percentage

              $resultpercentage = mysql_query("SELECT profilevalue_1, profilevalue_2, profilevalue_3 FROM table_profilevalues WHERE profilevalue_user_id = '$count_userid' LIMIT 1");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultpercentage)) {
              $empty_count = 0;
              $count = count($row);
              for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                if ($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === '-1' || $row[$i] === 'NULL')
                  $empty_count++;
              $profile_percent_user = ((int) (100 * (1 - $empty_count / ($count - 1))));


              // SAVE PROFILE PERCENTAGE
              $profile_percentage_query = "UPDATE table_users SET user_profilepercentage='$profile_percent_user' WHERE user_id='$count_userid' LIMIT 1";
              $database->database_query($profile_percentage_query);
            } 

          $count_userid++;
        }
```

Anyone see the problem here?

Best regards

Comment: Just skimming your code, but why couldn't you do this all in SQL with a single `UPDATE` statement?  Also, for debugging, add some echo statements in your code so you can see what is going on, and where you might be getting stuck.  Are you sure that the loop isn't ending, rather than just taking a long time?

Comment: Hello Brad, how would you do this with a single SQL UPDATE statement? Does SQL have a loop function? And yes, the while loop seems to never end, I tried with <5 then the website isn't available and the server load goes high.

Comment: I don't believe there is a need for any sort of loop, is there?  Can you describe what you are trying to do?  I'm reading through your code, and it isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  It looks as if you could just do `UPDATE table_users SET user_profilepercentage=AVG(profilevalue_1, profilevalue_2, profilevalue_3)` or something similar.

Comment: For one thing, `$resultpercentage` will contain 1 value because of your "`LIMIT 1`" in the SQL query, correct? So what is the following `while` loop looping over? And the following `count` will only ever be 1 which negates the `for` loop that comes after it.

Comment: @Brad I want to accomplish that in each loop it will go to the user_id, check all filled in profile fields, calculate the percentage and put this percentage into a column of my users table. Your UPDATE code will set 0 for the first user_id, and it will not loop, right?

Comment: @Carlos, Why would it do that?  `UPDATE` will touch everything allowed by the `WHERE` clause.  If there is no `WHERE` clause, everything will be updated.  Try it.

Comment: @gaoshan88 I set the LIMIT to 1 because in each loop, just need to select 1 resource and update 1 resource for each looped user_id. Is this that wrong? Should I remove?

Comment: Loops are for iterating over collections. If you only have 1 result you don't need a loop.

Comment: @Brad Sorry, you're right, it goes trought all rows, but it still SET 0 as result of the AVG command. Could the problem be that I have two diffrent tables, in the one table I count the profile fields and then put the result into the diffrent users table?

Comment: @gaoshan88 You were right, the problem was the LIMIT 1, removed it, now it works! If you will post this as an answer, I can mark it as correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, $resultpercentage will contain 1 value because of your "LIMIT 1" in the SQL query, correct? So what is the following while loop looping over? And the following count will only ever be 1 which negates the for loop that comes after it.

tl;dr: Remove the "LIMIT 1" so you can iterate over all of the result.